# C create Array and check for Input Error

Tags: c, arrays, validation, input, conditional-statements

Simple question. I am trying to build a simple script that will ask you for a number. That integer will be the amount of numbers you will enter in total. Then your program finds the biggest number and the smallest. And I have build that. Easy.

```
  int CHECK=100;
  int a[50],size,i,max,min;

  printf("\nEnter the size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  max=a[0];
  for(i=1;i<size;i++){
     if(max<a[i])
       max=a[i];
  }
 printf("\nLargest element: %d",max);
 printf("\n");
 min=a[0];
 for(i=1;i<size;i++){
  if(min>a[i])
       min=a[i];
}
printf("Smallest element: %d",small);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

My question is, how can I tell to check for conditions. For instance, the user can input only positive numbers and smaller than 100. So if you enter -4 or 201 an Error has to be displayed telling you to try again.
Any ideas as of how we can do that in a simple way. Or even point me to the right direction.

I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you feel that you must store the numbers? Consider looking for the smallest/largest as each number is entered, then you don't have to have a static limit (`50`) on how many numbers can be accepted. Designing programs to not have static limits is generally preferable.

Comment: Side issue: `scanf()` is *terrible* for inputting values, because if it can't match the input to the format string (e.g. if a letter like "A" was typed) then it will leave the remaining characters in the input buffer and they will screw up the next call to `scanf()`.

Comment: Once you replace `scanf()` with something nicer, like `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` (DO NOT use `gets()` because it can cause a buffer overflow!): What you need to do is check whether the result matched your expectations (e.g. the return value from `sscanf()` should be 1, and the value should be in range), and if it's not then print an error message and do `--i`, so that the effect of the loop causes `i` to remain unchanged on the next loop cycle.

Comment: You guys have all been incredible help. Thank you very much. I am just trying to learn C on my own and still trying to understand scanf() or fgets() and all the different types. 
But j_random_hacker you have a point. I will try with fgets() and see what I can do.

Comment: You're welcome :) One more tip: if you stick a "@" directly in front of a person's username in a comment, they'll be notified.

Comment: @j_random_hacker gotcha! And again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It really is quite easy - at least as easy as in Python.  I'm sticking with your `scanf` to illustrate the condition, but see @j_random_hacker's comments (++).

```
for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    if ( a[i] < 0 || a[i] > 99 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number '%d' is out of range, try again: ", a[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```

By the way you had a missing `{` in your code, I assume it was a transposition error.  (Consistent indentation will help pickup errors like this - it is not just a good idea in Python).

Comment: Thank you cdarke. Indeed it is quite easy now that I saw your sample. I appreciate you taking the time and helping me out.